# How to sort a nested object based on key name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, javascript-objects

I have a nested object that looks like this.I want to sort this in ascending and descending order based on the alphabetical order of Districtnames.

```
var data = 
{"DistrictC":{"population":105597},
"DistrictB":{"population":36842},
"DistrictA":{"population":238142}}
```

Expected output in ascending order is shown below.I also need to sort in descending order.

```
{"DistrictA":{"population":238142},
"DistrictB":{"population":36842},
"DistrictC":{"population":105597}}
```

Comment: Objects are not really meant to have order. JS Engines will keep order, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key/value pairs and then sort on the keys using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
const data = {
  "DistrictC":{"population":105597},
  "DistrictB":{"population":36842},
  "DistrictA":{"population":238142}
}

const sorted = Object.entries(data)
  .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB));

console.log(sorted);
```

You could make that result a bit easier to work with by collapsing the key/value arrays into objects using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
// same as before
const data = {
  "DistrictC":{"population":105597},
  "DistrictB":{"population":36842},
  "DistrictA":{"population":238142}
}

// same as before
const sorted = Object.entries(data)
  .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB));

const collapsed = sorted.map(([district, value]) => ({ district, ...value }));

// ascending
console.log(collapsed);

// descending
console.log(collapsed.reverse());
```

Comment: How to sort in descending order as well?

Comment: It is not sorting based on population....

Comment: It shouldn't. Read the question (  `ascending and descending order based on the alphabetical order of Districtnames` )  :P

Comment: In the reverse alphabetical order of district names , not based on population.

Comment: To reverse the order you could either swap keyA and keyB in the localeCompare expression: `keyB.localeCompare(keyA)`, or just append `.reverse()` after the sort.

Comment: Or add a `-` before `keyA.localeCompare(keyB))` (so `-keyA.localeCompare(keyB));` . But I think just using reverse on the initial sorted array is the best option.

Comment: ^ right. or that. `reverse` is going to be the easiest to read.